# Jquery : Set Value for a Range in a Dictionary

Tags: jquery, dictionary, range

I want to set values to a range in a jquery dictionary object somthing like this

```
var temp_dict = {'1-10': 'Woolen', '11-25':'Light Woolen', '26-36':'Light Cotton'}
```

here the keys `1-10, 11-25, 26-36` is different ranges of temprature. I want to store this in a dictionary and then call them like this :

```
alert(temp_dict[15]);
```

so that it checks in the range and returns appropriate result.

is there any way i could achieve this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getTemp(t) {
    for (var key in temp_dict) {
        var range = key.split("-");
        if (t >= range[0] && t <= range[1])
            return temp_dict[key];
    }
}

var temp = getTemp(15);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/WPXdx/

Comment: thanks for your quick response. However that function might return an error if we store a negative temperature range for example : -20 to -10 degrees. Would saving this range with a different delimiter will be a possibility to overcome this problem ? ex if we save it as -20:-10 and then split it using ":" delimiter ?

Comment: @Amyth Yes, absolutely. Using colon `:` as delimiter will be the easiest solution.